# All arrow keys in dired+ buffer mapped to M-O

Tags: key-bindings, dired, emacs-nox

For some reason when I press Up, Down, Left or Right keys on keyboard in dired+ mode, emacs reads them all as `M-O` key, which I found out by `describe-key` command in dired+ buffer. I have no config regarding diredp in my config, just that:

```
(use-package dired+
  :ensure t)
```

Also, when pressing arrow keys in diredp in minibuffer appears `change owner of auto-save-list`, and depending on Up, Down, Left, Right, character appear in input field are A, B, D, C, which is even more confusing.

In ordinary `dired` buffer arrow keys appears normally. Also I'm working in `emacs-nox` session.

Comment: Can you reproduce this starting with `emacs -Q`? If so, please post a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` and loading `dired+.el` with just `M-x load-file`. If you don't see the problem with `emacs -Q`, even after loading `dired+.el`, then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Also, please mention your Emacs version: `M-x emacs-version`. (I don't know what `emacs-nox` means.)

Comment: Neither vanilla Dired nor Dired+ binds `M-O` (by which I guess you mean `M-S-o`) or `M-o` to `dired-do-chown`, which is sems to be the command that is getting invoked when you use an arrow key. They also do not bind arrow keys to that command. A guess is that something else in your init file is causing this.

Comment: @Drew yes, I checked with starting `emacs -Q` and loading one diredp.el file - problem reproduces identically. My emacs version is `GNU Emacs 25.3.1`, and `emacs-nox` is package for term-only emacs, its available for lots of platform, specifically mine is arch linux package.

Comment: It sounds like an `emacs-nox` problem, to me. But maybe someone else has something to offer here. I try `emacs -Q -nw`, which gives me Emacs in terminal mode. I load `dired+.el`. I see no problem with the keys. You can try commenting out sections of the Dired+ code, to narrow down the problem, if you want. Start with the code that binds keys: search for `;;; Key Bindings.` If commenting out all Dired+ key bindings fixes the problem then comment out 1/2 of them, then 1/4, 1/8, etc. until you find which bindings seem to interfere.

Comment: Do you start your `emacs-nox` using `emacs -Q -nw`? If not , try that.

Comment: `emacs -Q -nw` does nothing

Comment: I was bitten by this issue 3 years ago and [wrote briefly about it](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2m6nvu/dont_bind_mo_if_you_want_to_use_arrow_keys_in/) on reddit/r/emacs.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37368/dired-key-binding-issues-in-terminal-emacs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dired+ key binding issues in terminal emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37368/dired-key-binding-issues-in-terminal-emacs)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by configuring `dired+` followingly:

```el
(use-package dired+
  :config
  ;; This binding messes with the arrow keys, for some reason.
  (unbind-key "M-O" dired-mode-map))
```

Comment: That removes the Dired+ binding of `M-S-o` (aka `M-O`). It does not answer the question of why the arrow keys are getting redirected to `M-O`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a user option, **`diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys`**, that has this effect:

> `diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys` is a variable defined in `dired+.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means bind some keys that might not work in a text-only terminal.
>
> This applies to keys that use modifiers Meta and Shift together.
> If you use Emacs in text-only terminal and your terminal does not
> support the use of such keys then customize this option to nil.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You might try customizing that option to `nil`.

The Dired+ doc has this prominent section (in the Commentary of [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)):

> ### If You Use Dired+ in Terminal Mode
>
> By default, Dired+ binds some keys that can be problematic in some
> terminals when you use Emacs in terminal mode (i.e., `emacs -nw`).
> This is controlled by option `diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys`.
>
> In particular, keys that use modifiers Meta and Shift together can
> be problematic.  If you use Dired+ in a text-only terminal, and you
> find that your terminal does not support such keys, then you might
> want to customize the option to set the value to `nil`, and then
> bind the commands to some other keys, which your terminal
> supports.
>
> The problematic keys used by Dired+ include these:
>
> ```
>  `M-M`   (aka `M-S-m`)   - `diredp-chmod-this-file`
>  `M-O`   (aka `M-S-o`)   - `diredp-chown-this-file`
>  `M-T`   (aka `M-S-t`)   - `diredp-touch-this-file`
>  `C-M-B` (aka `C-M-S-b`) - `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file`
>  `C-M-G` (aka `C-M-S-g`) - `diredp-chgrp-this-file`
>  `C-M-R` (aka `C-M-S-r`) - `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir`
>  `C-M-T` (aka `C-M-S-t`) - `dired-do-touch`
>  `M-+ M-B`   (aka `M-+ M-S-b`) -  `diredp-do-bookmark-dirs-recursive`
>  `M-+ C-M-B` (aka `M-+ C-M-S-b`) - `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file-recursive`
>  `M-+ C-M-T` (aka `M-+ C-M-S-t`) - `diredp-do-touch-recursive`
> ```
>
> (See also `(info "(org) TTY keys")` for more information about
> keys that can be problematic in a text-only terminal.)

HTH. Sorry for any trouble.