# Dired+ key binding issues in terminal emacs

Tags: key-bindings, dired, terminal-emacs

Using the [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) library, and running Emacs in a terminal, 
all arrow keys in dired buffers invoke `M-O` (which is bound to `diredp-chown-this-file`) instead of correct `<left> <right> <up> <down>` events.

Non-dired buffer types work as expected.

How to solve it?

Comment: Does this still happen if you run `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: No, I think, dired+ is causing this (but GUI mode is OK).

Comment: Do `C-b`, `C-f`, `C-n`, and `C-p` work?

Comment: C-n works (go one line down), rest is not working (as a navigation in buffer) becouse I remapped these keys to other functions (which are working in dired buffer).

Comment: What does `C-h k <left>` report? (for both `emacs -nw -Q` where things are working normally, and `emacs -nw` where things are broken).

Answer (score 2):

See this part of the Commentary in [`dired+.el`(https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el):

```
;;  If You Use Dired+ in Terminal Mode
;;  ----------------------------------
;;
;;  By default, Dired+ binds some keys that can be problematic in some
;;  terminals when you use Emacs in terminal mode (i.e., `emacs -nw').
;;  This is controlled by option
;;  `diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys'.
;;
;;  In particular, keys that use modifiers Meta and Shift together can
;;  be problematic.  If you use Dired+ in terminal mode, and you find
;;  that your terminal does not support such keys then you might want
;;  to customize the option to set the value to `nil', and then bind
;;  the commands to some other keys, which your terminal supports.
;;  
;;  Regardless of the option value, unless Emacs is in terminal mode
;;  the keys are bound by default.  The problematic keys used by
;;  Dired+ include these:
;;
;;    `M-M'   (aka `M-S-m')   - `diredp-chmod-this-file'
;;    `M-O'   (aka `M-S-o')   - `diredp-chown-this-file'
;;    `M-T'   (aka `M-S-t')   - `diredp-touch-this-file'
;;    `C-M-B' (aka `C-M-S-b') - `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file'
;;    `C-M-G' (aka `C-M-S-g') - `diredp-chgrp-this-file'
;;    `C-M-R' (aka `C-M-S-r') - `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir'
;;    `C-M-T' (aka `C-M-S-t') - `dired-do-touch'
;;    `M-+ M-B'   (aka `M-+ M-S-b') -
;;        `diredp-do-bookmark-dirs-recursive'
;;    `M-+ C-M-B' (aka `M-+ C-M-S-b') -
;;        `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file-recursive'
;;    `M-+ C-M-T' (aka `M-+ C-M-S-t') - `diredp-do-touch-recursive'
;;
;;  (See also `(info "(org) TTY keys")' for more information about
;;  keys that can be problematic in terminal mode.)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Drew, I solved this issue by putting this to init:

```
(setq diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one or all of this:

```
(require 'dired+)                                                              
(setq diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys nil)

(defun dired-custom()                                                          
  "conf dired-mode"
  (diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir t)                                           
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-O") nil))                                             
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-custom)

(eval-after-load 'dired-mode '(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-O") nil))
```